How to fix gulp-typescript high severity vulnerabilities using npm?
When I run npm install I get high severity vulnerabilities warning.
Running npm audit fix gives me the following report
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6

Running npm audit fix --force does not fix the problem and I get the same report. How can this vulnerability issue be fixed in gulp-typescript?
